# oracle apex 5.0 data load transformation rule pl/sql code

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Hi I am trying to see if this code would work for Apex 5.0.1

I have a data loading procedure that end users are using both upper and lower case, but in some cases they need to and in some other cases they don't.

So to remove the need for them to know when to use it on the upload I was trying to create this data transformation rule.

[Data transformation rule page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5s4Z.png)

```
DECLARE
    V_ASSET_NA (Varchar2);
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN :ASSET_DLVRY_MTHD IN ('MEDIA REPOSITORY', 'PRIVATENET') THEN
            UPPER(ASSET_NA);
        ELSE
            LOWER(ASSET_NA);
    END CASE;
END;
```

If someone could check the PL/SQL I would be very grateful.

Comment: William Robertson please say what you needed too. I am still learning so am game for any comment you have sir.

Comment: so I have change the Pl/SQL a little based off someone else posting something similar. but not sure what the return would be.   `code` DECLARE
    v_ASSET_NA (Varchar2);
BEGIN
    CASE
       WHEN :ASSET_DLVRY_MTHD IN ('MEDIA REPOSITORY', 'PRIVATENET', 'Joneslink) THEN
          v_ASSET_NA := UPPER;
        ELSE
            v_ASSET_NA := LOWER;
    END CASE;
 RETURN V_ASSET_NA;
END; `code`

Comment: can you let us know why the difference in text case is important in your scenario? I'm asking because in most cases, you can just save all entries in either uppercase or lowercase to the database, in order to have a uniform output later on (in terms of text case).

Comment: In certain scenarios the asset name is searchable with in our on systems but it is case sensitive. Trust me i asked and yes that would be a lot easier.

Comment: I have tried a few more version of this PL/SQL and still no luck. If someone could guide me in the right direction.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work

```
DECLARE
    V_ASSET_NA (Varchar2);
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN :ASSET_DLVRY_MTHD IN ('MEDIA REPOSITORY', 'PRIVATENET') THEN
            UPPER(ASSET_NA);
        ELSE
            LOWER(ASSET_NA);
    END CASE;
RETURN V_ASSET_NA;
END;
```

I was missing a return value... :(